# Imaginary argument in bessel function for a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topological-insulators, special-functions

I am solving for the continuum model of haldane model with one of the site being a potential well. The Dirac equation for a topologically non trivial case gives a solution for the states in the band gap as $J_0(ikr)$.

What does a radial wavefunction of the form $J_0(ikr)$ signify in comparison to $J_0(kr)$ where k is a constant.

Comment: $J_0(iz)$ simplifies to a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions), $I_0(z)$, which grows exponentially with $z$, though depending on context there may be reasons to keep it as $J_0(iz)$. Other than that, though, what do you want to know?  What do you mean by "signify"? To a good extent, it simply is what it is, so unless you give more context and  better indications of what you're confused about, this is very hard to answer.

Comment: The differential equation which is to be solved is $f''(r)+\frac{f'(r)}{r}+(k-\frac{j-\frac{1}{2}}{r^2})f(r)=0$. The constant k is negative for the topologically non trivial case. Does this equation simplify to modified bessel equation? It has a solution in the form of modified bessel function of second kind. Does it signify existence of edge states?

Comment: The only difference between the Bessel equation and the modified Bessel equation is the sign of $k$. If your question is about the connection with the specific solution chosen for that equation and the presence of edge states, then make that clear in the post.